# MongoDB Update many item in nested object by array of Id

Tags: mongodb

How to update some of the nested objects found by thair Id in MongoDB.

In the below case, only the first Item will be updated!

Update all nested objects in updateMany.

```
"Parent":[{
        "Child": [{
                "_id": 5f26fad5b34a304dfc1dd16a,
                "isActive": false,                    
            }, {
                "_id": 5f26fad5b34a304dfc1dd16c,
                "isActive": false,                    
            }, {
                "_id": 5f2705281b42ea2de8b7c9e2,
                "isActive": false,                    
            } 
        ],
        "name": "Paretn1"
    },  
]



    parent.updateMany(
    { 
      "child._id": { $in: [ObjectId('5f26fad5b34a304dfc1dd16a'), ObjectId('5f26fad5b34a304dfc1dd16c') 
    ]} 
    },
    { $set: { "child.$.isActive": true } },
    { multi: true },
    () => {
      console.log('done')
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as below

```
parent.updateMany(
{ 
   "child._id": { $in: 
              [ObjectId('5f26fad5b34a304dfc1dd16a'), 
              ObjectId('5f26fad5b34a304dfc1dd16c') 
              ]} 
    },
    { $set: { "child.$[element].isActive": true } },
    { "arrayFilters": [{ "elem._id": {'$in' :[  
              ObjectId('5f26fad5b34a304dfc1dd16a'), 
              ObjectId('5f26fad5b34a304dfc1dd16c')] } }], "multi": true }, 
    () => {
        console.log('done')
    }
  );
```

Comment: This answer worked for me. I had to change `[element]` to `[elem]` to match the arrayFilter. Thank You!